# If x equals something then do not run function

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and HTML. I have this line of code in my JavaScript file:

```
if (q1 == '' && q2 == '' && q3 == '' && q4 == '' && q5 == '') {alert("You must enter a question");thisform.q1.focus();return false;}
```

Basically, q1 q2 and so on are textboxes and if they are left blank an alert pops up and says You must enter a question. In my HTML file I have this line of code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add() {
var num = document.getElementById("n1").value;
if(num == '') num = 0;
document.getElementById("n1").value = parseInt(num ,10) + 1; 
var num = document.getElementById("n2").value;
if(num == '') num = 0;
document.getElementById("n2").value = parseInt(num ,10) + 1;
var num = document.getElementById("n3").value;
if(num == '') num = 0;
document.getElementById("n3").value = parseInt(num ,10) + 1;
var num = document.getElementById("n4").value;
if(num == '') num = 0;
document.getElementById("n4").value = parseInt(num ,10) + 1;
var num = document.getElementById("n5").value;
if(num == '') num = 0;
document.getElementById("n5").value = parseInt(num ,10) + 1;
}
</script>
```

Then Later:

```
<INPUT onclick="addQ(myForm);add();" value="Add Question" id="question add" type=button>
```

Is there any way that I can make the add() function not execute if my alert pops up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
<INPUT onclick="if(!addQ(myForm)) {return false;} add();" value="Add Question" id="question add" type=button>
```

then add a `return true;` to the end of function `addQ()`.

```
function addQ(myForm){
    ....
    if (q1 == '' && q2 == '' && q3 == '' && q4 == '' && q5 == '') {alert("You must enter a question");thisform.q1.focus();return false;}
    ......
    .....
    return true;
}
```

or

```
<INPUT onclick="if(addQ(myForm) === false) {return false;} add();" value="Add Question" id="question add" type=button>
```

Comment: Ok it works...to an extent. When I do enter something into the form I want it to run the add() function.

Comment: Add a `return true` to the end of function `addQ`

Comment: Do you mean in stead of if(!addQ(myform)) {return false;} it would be if(!addQ(myform)) {return true:} because that does the same thing and does not run add()